# making matrices that start from 0 to n

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, dimensions

I was wondering how could one make a 4*4 matrix that starts from 0 to 16?

I don't want to do it manually.
imagine doing it for a 10*10 matrix that starts from 0 to 100. lol.
there has to be some way to do it more efficiently than to do it manually.

Comment: Do you want it to go 0 to 15 or 1 to 16?

Comment: i guess if you want a 4*4 matrix, you should have it started from 1 to 17.

Comment: Usually, when someone says “from 0 to 16”, that includes both 0 and 16. It seems that you meant to include 0 and exclude 16.

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes bro. sorry. my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easiest to do using numpy. Try the following.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.reshape(np.arange(16),(4,-1)))
```

The result:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]]
```

If you instead want the numbers to go from 1 to 16, you could simply add 1, as in

```
1 + np.reshape(np.arange(16),(4,-1))
```

Comment: oh man. thank you so much. I really appreciate it that you spent time to teach me this. I wish you happiness and meaningful life.

Comment: If interested to just use pure `Python` check this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808719/

Comment: @awannabecs Glad to help. If you’re satisfied with my answer, I would appreciate it if you could “accept” the answer by clicking the check mark below the arrows.

Comment: I did it bro. wish you the best. again thanks.

Comment: @DanielHao thanks Daniel. I'm really grateful .