# How to create a matrix - def createMatrix(rows: int, cols: int) in python

Tags: python

I am  3 weeks old in my Python Journey. I came across this exercise where I need to create a 2D matrix using a function. The number of rows and columns of the matrix should be passed inside the function parameters on function call while the matrix elements should come from range() in respect to parameter values.
Am trying to handle it like this:

```py
def createMatrix(row, col):
    mat = []
    for in range(row):
        mat.append([])
        for in range(col):
|
```

This is what I was trying before I stuck there I stuck. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to define another list before executing inner loop, append zeros *(or whatever you want)* every iteration of inner loop and finally append this list to `mat` after inner loop execution.

Comment: Do you want the `matrix` to be filled some `consecutive` numbers? Eg. 1, 2, 3...? Or just `0`.  Above post has pointed you the right way.

Comment: Exactly that's what I want.

Comment: I want the matrix to be filled with real numbers 0-9, specified with range(row) or range(col)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could this `List Comprehension` way:

```
def create_matrix(row, col):
    ''' create a 2D matrix by consecutive numbers - starting 1 - or change to whatever number in code

    '''

    matrix = [[ j + (col *i) for j in range(1, col+1)] # 1
                             for i in range(row)]

    return matrix
```

print(create_matrix(4, 4))

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Comment: You can make it a bit clearer using [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) with all it's power: `[[i + j for j in range(col)] for i in range(1, row * col + 1, col)]`. It should be slightly more efficient as multiplication performed just once.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, both answers looks the same to me as a beginner. I just got happy for getting what I wanted but honestly I  don't understand the use of i and j behind a loop. Are these two may be special inbuilt characters recognized by python or something else. Please provide me documentation where I can study more about them if  applicable. Thank you

Comment: @philipnyankena, and that is the problem. You need to understand code you're using. Me and Daniel used [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions). `i` and `j` is just a variable names.

Comment: You can try to convert the code to simpler `2 for-loops` so that you can compare both ways.  Try this platform - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

this creates a 2d Matrix filled with 0:

```
def create_matrx(row, col):

    grid = []

    for row in range(col):

        row = [0 for _ in range(col)]

        grid.append(row)

    return grid
```

creates a 2d Matrix with a given element

```
def create_matrx(row, col,element):

    grid = []

    for row in range(col):

        row = [element for _ in range(col)]

        grid.append(row)

    return grid
```

creates a 2d Matrix filled with 0 to row+col

```
def create_matrx(row, col):

    grid = []

    for row in range(col):

        row = [row+col for _ in range(col)]

        grid.append(row)

    return grid
```

Comment: @OlvinRoght  thank you for answering but I don't understand what you mean with append zeros

Comment: @philipnyankena, I've meant literally `row.append(0)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght, thanks for that it created a 2D matrix with filled with 0 elements. But what if  I need other real elements specified by what is given to the function parameters. Eg: row=2 col=3

Comment: @philipnyankena I Gerda answered that not OlvinRoght xd